# What changes are needed for .NET framework upgrade from 4.6 to 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8, .net-4.6

I am working on project upgrade for the 1st time. I have a solution built upon 4.6 version of .NET framework. When I opened it very first time in VS 2022, I got a dialog box saying upgrade to 4.8 and I clicked OK on that. Now I can see that my application is running on 4.8.

1. I am confused and curios to know about what all other things are I need to check to make sure my application is running on .NET 4.8 version.
2. I can see that my .csproj file is updated automatically. .Csproj file contains the TargetFrameworkVersion updated to 4.8.
3. I can see new package.config file is newly added to solution. It is containing all the package references.
4. In web.config also contains the changes  tag.

Do I need to check in all these 3 files in git or just .csproj file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there are no breaking changes between 4.6 and 4.8, so your application should run without any code changes.

Comment: There is a guide for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/ Google for "something migration guide" will usually find you something if there is.

Comment: Are you asking what you need to check to see whether it is targeting .NET 4.8 or what you need to do to check that it will run successfully after changing the targeted framework? They are two very different things. That said, both answers are simple. In the former case, if VS says it's targeting .NET Framework 4.8 then it is. In the latter case, you should perform the same tests that you did to ensure that app ran successfully on the previous framework.

Comment: Can you show us what has changed in your .csproj and web.config. It's likely that all these changes should be commited and added to source control but without knowing exactly what they are we cannot really comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are no breaking changes between .NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Framework 4.8. So it is not expected that you see any problems compiling and running your application. The installed runtime version is 4.8 on any computer running something later than Windows 7 anyway. So you have been running your application against the .NET 4.8 runtime for a long time already.

This will be different if you decide to update to .NET 6.0 or later. There are some breaking changes there, but for most applications, even that is doable with reasonable effort.

Comment: My app is running fine. I just wanted to know if I am going in right direction. Can you please help on what files I need to check in. I have updated my question for more insight. TIA.

Comment: You should check in the .csproj file (of course), and the packages.config, too. Instead of the packages.config, you could also directly update the csproj to use the new SDK-style syntax with embedded package includes. Google for "convert csproj to sdk format" if you want to do this. I'm not sure what would be the content of web.config, but I guess it should also go into git.

Comment: "The installed runtime version is 4.8 on any computer running something later than Windows 7 anyway" - it's not true. .NET is not a part of Windows. Any .NET framework release can be installed on newest versions of Windows. Anyway, migration to the latest release (4.8) is a good choice.

Comment: @rotabor While I haven't tried this, it is at least not commonly done. By default, only the last version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework 4.8 is the latest supported release. It installs with VS if the framework support option is selected. But you are not forced to upgrade your app. Just install .NET Framework 4.6 and continue to work.

If you already upgraded your app and don't want to come back to 4.6, you can synchronize your local files with git.

Comment: Which files? This is where I am confused. I know .csproj file will be chaged. But I can see the change in web.config also. Do I need to check in that as well?

Comment: @dotnetlearner Can you edit your question and show us what has actually changed in those files?

Comment: I have updated the question now. Can you please suggest

Comment: If you want to continue with upgraded project, you need to update git with newest files (all files) from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Q: Do I need to check in all these 3 files in git or just .csproj file?

   - A: Yes.  The below files should be version controlled as they will change when adding/deleting code files (.csproj), when adding new references to NuGet pkgs (.csproj/package.config) and web app cfg changes (web.config).  If in doubt, add them to code repo.  Can learn when they change as you go.  Only files not worth adding to code repo are ones which are auto generated by compiler like .exe files.

     1. .csproj - project details like code files.
     2. package.config - details of NuGet packages used by project.
     3. web.config - details about web app cfg like db connection string etc.

The following may also give you more background about migrating code from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to 4.8.  You asked about v4.6 but v4.6.1 is very similar.

[Running 4.6.1 application on 4.8 framework: What issues will I encounter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950691/running-4-6-1-application-on-4-8-framework-what-issues-will-i-encounter)

[.net-4.6.1](/questions/tagged/.net-4.6.1)[.net-4.8](/questions/tagged/.net-4.8)